# Dual Booting Ubuntu and Debian

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, 20.04, debian

I am a Debian user and it has been running great for me. I am planning to dual boot Ubuntu on it as I can experience both the worlds since it feels a lot different to me (though you'd think me as a mad man and would maybe comment that both of them are of the same derivatives, but to be honest with you, they are two different worlds for me) and I am planning to add Ubuntu. I have tried several methods but every time I try, I fail. I saw a couple lot of videos, but they don't work out for me. For some reason, the Ubuntu installer is not detecting Debian and is causing a problem to me.

A few details:

1) Manufacturer: Dell

2) Model: LATITUDE E5440

3) The primary OS and what kind of boot does it run on: Debian and works on UEFI mode

4) The bootable device working on: UEFI mode

5) What is my goal: To have a common GRUB screen and to be able to switch to both the Operating Systems

6) What partitions have I assigned to my primary OS: Manual (I created a lot of partitions in which it is assigned to a specific task. For eg: A single partition to the root partition /, another partition to swap, another one to /opt,etc.)

7) I even tried using the code `ubiquity -b` which disables the bootloader of the Ubuntu OS so that I can merge it with that of Debian's. I want it to merge with the Debian GRUB bootloader since Debian is the main OS which all other Linux OS depend upon.

I am sincerely thankful to you guys out there who are willing to solve everyone's doubts and the person who asks, feels a satisfaction that the person has come to his rescue and cleared his doubts.

Once again thanking you.

EDIT: I would also like to attach a screenshot of my current Debian layout.
[This is the image hyperlink.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9u8lY.png)
[The sda11, sda12 and sda13 are assigned for the Ubuntu OS.The sda11 has the / mounting point, the sda12 has the /home mounting point and the sda13 is the linux-swap][2]

I would like to post the text of the terminal window:

```
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ACF0 (scsi)

Disk /dev/sda: 320GB

Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B

Partition Table: gpt

Disk Flags: 

Number| Start   | End     |Size    |File system   | Name | Flags

 1  |    1049kB |  22.6GB |  22.6GB | ext4

12  |    22.6GB | 45.0GB |  22.4GB | ext4

 2  |    45.0GB | 55.0GB |  10.0GB | ext4

11  |    55.0GB | 90.0GB | 35.0GB | ext4

 3  |    90.0GB | 90.5GB | 500MB  | fat32  |        |   boot, esp

 4  |    90.5GB | 118GB  | 27.5GB | ext4

13  |    118GB  | 121GB  |  3000MB | linux-swap(v1)

 5  |    145GB  | 190GB  | 45.0GB | ext4

 6  |    190GB  | 220GB  | 30.0GB | ext4

 7  |    235GB  | 258GB  | 22.5GB | ext4

 8  |    280GB  | 299GB  | 19.0GB | ext4

 9  |    299GB  | 300GB  | 1000MB | linux-swap(v1)

10  |    301GB  | 320GB  | 18.6GB | ext4


Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.

Error: /dev/sr0: unrecognised disk label

Model: HL-DT-ST DVD+-RW GU90N (scsi)

Disk /dev/sr0: 25.6MB

Sector size (logical/physical): 2048B/2048B

Partition Table: unknown
```

Disk Flags:

For some reason, this is where it stops.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "the Ubuntu installer [does] not [detect] Debian ". Why do you think so? What does it detect?

Comment: Hello @mikewhatever, on the partitioning page, where it is supposed to be displaying "Ubuntu detected Debian" or something like that, It says "There is currently no operating system installed on the system. What would you like to do?". There are only two options, either erase whatever is on the system and install Ubuntu or the option something else, which takes you to manual partitioning.

Comment: Is Debian encrypted? What is the current layout - `sudo parted -l`. You can add info to the question with the <edit> button.

Comment: Hello @mikewhatever, I have given the snapshot of my debian and the ubuntu space allocation. Please have a look at them.

Comment: I guess you've tried to post a screenshot of a terminal window. That is a bad way to show text output. I can't see it. Copy/paste the output instead.

Comment: Hi @mikewhatever, I have done it according to your needs. Please have a look.

Comment: Better not to have swap nor /home. You can share data in a data partition between the installs. Ubuntu now uses swap file. So only one ext4 partition as / (root) required. You will get another UEFI boot entry using /EFI/ubuntu. But can easily change UEFI boot order to uses /EFI/grub from Debian with efibootmgr. Both systems should have no issue finding the other, but updates may make one or the other first in boot order again. Only use Something Else install option.

Comment: Thanks a lot @oldfred, something I must try. Thanks a lot!